# Currency formatting issue in Orbeon forms

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I am trying to use the currency field in Orbeon to show a value as a currency, e.g.: `$123123213213.00`. I am trying to do this with:

```
<fr:currency bind="balance">
    <xforms:alert>Required</xforms:alert>
</fr:currency>
```

I had the following problems:

1. The field has been losing its precision after 17 digits:
   `12345678901234567890123` changes to `12345678901234567000000.00` on blur.
2. I can't get the `maxlength` attribute on the `fr:currency` to work.

Has anyone come across such an issue and happened to solve it? Also, please let me know if there is any alternative to this problem, like some custom formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good point on the number precision. Support for very large amounts (without any set limit) is now implemented in the [currency component](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/currency), and will be included in [nightly builds](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download) starting 2011-03-07. For reference, see the [commit](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/fc24a849a2901c3e4dc0cd0a0ad57cfe3e37166a) and [bug](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315880&group_id=168&atid=350207).

As to the second part of your question regarding the `maxlength` attribute, simply the `fr:currency` doesn't support any such attribute. If you want to set the width of the field, you can use CSS.

Comment: The nightly build seems to be really unstable. i tried 5 times to install a stable one and failed every time. We even though managed to override the currency.js with a custom currency.js for the time being.    Can point me some link for that css field length limiting.

Comment: Still I am not able to limit the max-length in currency. Most of the people who asked about css for limiting length where shouted on in the forums, and none gave the answer. Please help with you suggestion!!!

Comment: First, let me make sure I understand your requirement: do you want to limit the visual width of the field, or the maximum number of digits users can enter?

Comment: My currency field should contain only 17 digit. Anything beyond 17 digit should not be allowed to enter. To be short, I am expecting something like a max-length feature for currency field.

Comment: The `fr:currency` doesn't support a `maxlength` attribute that would provide the equivalent functionality of the attribute you can put on an HTML input. Instead, I would use a bind in the model for this. For instance: `<xforms:bind name="balance" ref="…" constraint="length(.) le 17"/>`. This won't "physically" prevent users from typing more than 17 characters, but if they do, the control will be considered invalid.

Comment: The length(.) method seems to be not present, and since it was a currency field we didnt want to use the string-length(.). But still we are already doing a similar logic by using <xforms:bind name="balance" ref="…" constraint="number(.) &lt; 10000000000000000"/>

Comment: the currency.js file from the new orbeon 3.9 seems to be working when copied to orbeon 3.8 war. We where not able to successfully run our application using new orbeon 3.9 war on websphere.

Comment: @Babu, so you are good using the `currency.js` in 3.8? Most likely, at some point, you'll want to upgrade to 3.9. When doing so, you might want to review the "compatibility notes" in the 3.9 release notes: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/39.